# Override method on ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models, `Thing` and `Tag`. A thing has many tags:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Thing <ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end
```

I want to override `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`'s `proxy_association#concat` method is is what's called when you do something like:

```
Things.first.tags << Tag.create(name: "Some Tag")
```

How would one go about overriding this method?

Answer (score 0):

There is one widely used way to override any class methods, as well as add new methods or attributes to classes, however it is not always advisable to mess with big classes.

Having said that, do the following:

a. Add this line to your `environment.rb` file:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

Then, create the folder, as described above

```
/root/to/your/app/lib/core_ext
```

In there (or anywhere else you might guess - but to keep it simple and organized) you can add anything you want to override. In your case:

*activerecord_tag.rb*

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
    def concat
        # do your magic
    end
end
```

Please, bear in mind that you will have to restart your application server in order for changes to take effect.